# How can I add all the values in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have an array (or is it an object?) that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 5 
    [1] => 4 
    [2] => 3 
    [3] => 4 
    [4] => 4 
    [5] => 4 
    [6] => 4 
    [7] => 3 
    [8] => 4 
    [9] => 5 
    [10] => 3 
    [11] => 4 
    [12] => 4 
    [13] => 4 
    [14] => 3 
    [15] => 4 
    [16] => 4 
    [17] => 5
)
```

How do I add up all the values inside it. ie. 5 + 4 + 3 etc... Any ideas?

Comment: you know, it says Array for a reason ;)

Answer (score 5):

What you have is an array, not an object.

You can iterate over an array using a loop (like `foreach`), and then add all the values up to a variable.

```
$total = 0;
foreach($array as $val) $total += $val;
```

OR use a core function `array_sum()`.

```
array_sum($array);
```

Careful with the second one, because if there is a `float` value in your array, and you expect an integer value returned, this function will return a `float`.

Comment: How can add it like Array ([total]=>totalsum) ??

Comment: @AlwinAugustin Can you post a separate question on that, or post some code here the way you have it, because I am not getting your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` or `foreach` to iterate through the array and keep adding each element to a variable outside the scope of the loop. You can also take the easy route and use a built-in function.

```
$total = 0;
foreach($arr as $e)
    $total += $e;
```

or

```
$total = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
    $total += $arr[$i];
```

or

```
$total = array_sum($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP object you are referring to is called an Array. An array is an arrangement of objects usually in rows and columns.

To perform the operation of addition on all elements in the array, the following snippet may be used:

```
<?php 
     $array = array(5, 4, 3);
     foreach ($array as $value)
     {
          $total += $value;
     }
?>
```

This code snippet iterates through the array using the foreach construct. Each iteration takes a value of the array at the current pointer location and stores it in $value.

I hope this is helpful.