# Add up all int() values from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json, int

I've have a JSON file that I am parsing using `json_decode()` which outputs the contents of the JSON files as an array, This is a sample of the data output:

```
array(1) {
  ["petition"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["postal_districts"]=>
        array(2257) {
          ["DH4"]=>
          int(12)
          ["BT5"]=>
          int(14)
          ["WA9"]=>
          int(72)
          ["EH17"]=>
          int(5)
       }
    }
}
```

I am wanting to add up all the `int()` values from under "postal_districts" but at the moment I'm at a loss as to how I can achieve this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add all the values in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695140/php-add-up-values-in-object-array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they are all ints, you can try:

```
$sum = array_sum($arr['petition']['postal_districts']);
```

(see if [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) helps)

If not, filter them first:

```
$ints = array_filter($arr['petition']['postal_districts'], 'is_int');
$sum = array_sum($ints);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($array['petition']['postal_districts'] as $val)
    $sum += $val;
echo $sum;
```

Do you mean it?

Comment: If the values of the array are mixed you can through in some detection with `is_int` or `is_numeric` depending...

Comment: @prodigitalson I now, but user does not specify all values is integer or mixed. I suggested that integer.

Comment: I know... that comment was more for him than you. Your answer is correct based on the info given.